# How to create durable subscription to ibm mq amqp topic from java program?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, amqp, jms-topic

We have programmatically created subscriber to IBM MQ AMQP TOPIC with `createDurableSubscriber` by providing `clientId` and subscriber name.

We start the program so it subscribes to TOPIC and stop the program. Then send the msgs to topic and again start the receiver program again but we cannot receive the msgs sent and loose the messages which should not happen in case of durable subscription..

We can see amqp topic and its durable subscription when subscriber is connected using mqsc commands `DISPLAY TOPIC`, `DISPLAY TPSTATUS`, `DISPLAY TPSTATUS SUB`, `DISPLAY SUB SUBID` but not when subscriber program is stopped. We have defined attribute `DEFPSIST(YES)` and client(producer to topic) is sending persistent messages.

Where are the messages gone as we cannot see messages in durable queues of subscriber? Does it depends on expiry attribute?

Output of `DISPLAY SUB SUBID` for our subscriber when it is connected.

```
AMQ8096: WebSphere MQ subscription inquired.


SUBID("hex sub id")
   SUB(:private:CLINET01:TOPIC01)            TOPICSTR(TOPIC01)
   TOPICOBJ(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC)             DISTYPE(RESOLVED)
   DEST(SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.5F6B5C2524FB9AED)
   DESTQMGR(qm.name)                   PUBAPPID( )
   SELECTOR( )                             SELTYPE(NONE)
   USERDATA(010)
   PUBACCT(***************************************************)
   DESTCORL(***************************************************)
   DESTCLAS(MANAGED)                       DURABLE(YES)
   EXPIRY(0)                               PSPROP(MSGPROP)
   PUBPRTY(ASPUB)                          REQONLY(NO)
   SUBSCOPE(ALL)                           SUBLEVEL(1)
   SUBTYPE(API)                            VARUSER(FIXED)
   WSCHEMA(TOPIC)                          SUBUSER(mqm)
   CRDATE(2020-09-28)                      CRTIME(04:14:09)
   ALTDATE(2020-09-28)                     ALTTIME(04:14:09)
```

Subscriber id has private(not sure why) and client id but not subscriber name which is sub4

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.Queue;

import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.naming.Context;
import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.jms.Message;

public class AMQPQueueExample1 implements Runnable  {
private static final int DELIVERY_MODE = DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT;

public void run(){
try{
 Connection connection = null;
 Context context = new InitialContext();
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
 connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
 connection.setClientID("123");//("WHATS_MY_PURPOSE3"); // Why do we need clientID while publishing the TOPIC from consumer / publisher
 Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 Topic priceTopic = (Topic) context.lookup("myTopicLookup1");
 MessageConsumer subscriber1 = session.createDurableSubscriber(priceTopic,"sub420"); //"sub3");
System.out.println("TOPIC "+priceTopic);

connection.start();
while(true){
TextMessage   message1 = (TextMessage) subscriber1.receive(1000);
if(message1!=null)
           System.out.println("Subscriber 1 received : " + message1.getText());


}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

 public static void main(String[] args)  {

AMQPQueueExample1 amp=new AMQPQueueExample1();
 Thread thread = new Thread(amp);
thread.start();


 }
}
```

Values are taken from jndi.properties file for context factory and provider url.

Comment: If the subscription can be seen, and seen to be DURABLE(YES) when the program is running, but is not there when the program is stopped, this suggests that a normal end of the program closes and removes the subscription. You don't show what your code looks like, so cannot comment further without it. Take a look at what your subscriber program does at shutdown - does it remove the durable subscription? If so, what you describe is exactly what would be expected to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ... It was exactly what I checked as program was written by someone else ... and as I saw ..we are not calling unsubscribe on durable subscriber in program so basically we are not removing subscription ... I have edited question to show response of runmqsc command DISPLAY SUB SUBID(id)

Comment: IBM MQ 4 digit version is 8.0.0.5

Comment: @MoragHughson  Our EXPIRY is 0 ... should it be UNLIMITED and how to change it to UNLIMITED after or while creating subscription

Comment: @JoshMc Our EXPIRY is 0 ... should it be UNLIMITED and how to change it to UNLIMITED after or while creating subscription

Comment: @JoshMc code added

Comment: Results of runmqsc are : DIS SUB(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB) EXPIRY
     1 : DIS SUB(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB) EXPIRY
AMQ8096: WebSphere MQ subscription inquired.
   SUBID("sub id")
   SUB(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB)                 EXPIRY(UNLIMITED)

Comment: In jndi.properties we have topic.myTopicLookup1=TOPIC01 (our topic for consumer to subscribe) and we don't have any expiry set for this ... Can we set expiry ?If yes, How ?

Comment: Sagii, I missed the fact that your subscriber was using the Apache QPID JMS API, I mistakenly thought your publisher was using Apache QPID and your subscriber was IBM MQ JMS.  After reading your post [MQSeries.net: Sub getting deleted when java client closes](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=435581&highlight=#435581) finally understood.  See my answer.  If you can figure out how to specify those settings via Apache QPID JMS then you could do it programmatically, otherwise using a admin subscription may be the only way.  It appears the 0 default is expected if you don't set it.

Comment: I went through https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/tree/master/qpid-jms-client whether we could get idea how to set subscriber expiry but I could not find any such attribute

Answer (score 2):

It looks from the comments like you're using MQ 8.0.0.5? If that's the case then Apache Qpid JMS clients aren't supported with that version of MQ. I believe with that version a very basic non-durable subscribe *might* work, but any other JMS methods are unlikely to.

I suspect what is happening is the AMQP 1.0 flows from Qpid JMS aren't fully understood by that version of MQ, so the expiry of the subscription is being set to 0 rather than unlimited.

MQ 9.2 added support for more of the JMS 2.0 spec - although not every JMS feature. There is more information about the methods which are supported here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q125050_.htm

Creating durable subscribers and/or consumers should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... One workaround we are trying is to make subscriber unmodifiable by client ... Do we have any such way by which we can make subscriber created offline using runmqsc unmodifiable by client program so it may not be able to modify its expiry ... ?

Comment: No unfortunately there is no easy way to do that. The 9.2 version of MQ was specifically enhanced to support these types of AMQP client so the only workable solution is going to be an upgrade to MQ 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

An article from Matthew Whitehead "[MQ Light messaging from Microsoft®.NET™ (Part 4)](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/imwuc/viewdocument/mq-light-messaging-from-microsoft-3)" states the following:

> AMQP channels don’t support setting an unlimited expiry time for MQ Light subscriptions. While it is possible to create subscriptions that have a very long time-to-live, it isn’t possible to create subscriptions to exist forever.
>
> If you wish to create subscriptions that never expire you can do so by creating an MQ administered subscription and having MQ Light clients join and leave the subscription. This can also help to ensure that any messages published to a topic before the first subscribers have connected, aren’t lost completely. Read [my previous article](http://mmiandb.blogspot.com/2016/04/dont-lose-mq-light-messages-published.html) on joining MQ Light clients to administered subscriptions.
>
> Related AMQP Fields
>
> To provide the expiry capabilities described above MQ Light uses 2 features of AMQP 1.0:
>
> - Source Timeout
> - Source Expiry Policy
>
> The source timeout is used to specify the time in seconds that the subscription will expire.
>
> The source expiry policy is used to determine what causes the expiry timer to begin. MQ AMQP channels only support an expiry policy of link-detach, which means the timer starts as soon as the last link detaches from the subscription.

---

I searched and couldn't find a reference on how to set Source Timeout or Source Expiry Policy in Apache QPID, but the linked blog references setting expiry via a administratively defined subscription.  Based on the info in your question I think you can just define something like this ahead of time.  I have not specified `EXPIRY` because this will pick up `EXPIRY(UNLIMITED)` from `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB`:

```
DEFINE SUB(':private:CLINET01:TOPIC01') TOPICOBJ(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC) TOPICSTR('TOPIC01') DESTCLAS(MANAGED)
```

When you then connect your AMQP subscriber it will resume this existing subscription with the expiry set to `UNLIMITED`.

Comment: We already created subscriber with same name using runmqsc which had expiry UNLIMITED and but as soon as our subscriber connected through program .. expiry field value changed to 0 and after we closed our program which disconnected the subscriber , it was deleted by queue manager ...

Comment: Did you create with the same `DESTCLASS` in my example?

Comment: In both cases our DESTCLASS is MANAGED

Comment: I don't know the answer.  I would suggest upgrading to 9.0 and later or purchasing a extended support contract from IBM for v8.0 and opening a case with IBM.

Comment: One thing to ask : https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-amqp-0-x-6.4.0/jms-amqp-0-8-book/JMS-Client-0-8-Binding-URL.html https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-amqp-0-x-6.4.0/jms-amqp-0-8-book/index.html Can we use binding urls ... can you provide suggestion for this

Comment: can you give some idea about mcauser attribute on ibm mq objects ... its exact purpose ... we have 'mqm' user on subscriber created through our program ... we changed mcauser for AMQP channel from mqm to '' and to 'rubbish' but everytime we got the same user for subscriber ... and for mcauser 'root' on channel AMQP we got error """Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: MQRC 2436 MQRC_DURABILITY_NOT_ALLOWED [condition = amqp:internal-error]""" while connecting from client

Comment: Hi Sagii, that topic deserves it's own question.  But MCAUSER is just the user that MQ resolves the channel to, using mqm or blank is not good since this user has full permissions to MQ, coming in via a AMQP channel lessens the risk somewhat since you can only target topics, but it gives the AMQP client ability to publish or subscribe to ANY topic, as a MQ admin you would have no ability to restrict what topics each AMQP client can use.  I'm not sure why 'rubbish` would not cause an error but `root` does.  In the question you open please provide details on the objects you defined.

Comment: what is clean session flag and how can we set or unset it? We have found that clean session flag if unset while connecting to mq server, will result in storing subscribers and messages sent for it

Comment: I think the article I wrote was correct at the time of writing, but with MQ 9.2 isn't accurate any more. When we added support for Qpid JMS durable subscriptions in 9.2 we changed the behaviour to allow the MQ subscription to have unlimited expiration.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @MatthewWhitehead do you have a new link for this [url](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/Don_t_lose_MQ_Light_messages_published_before_a_receiver_has_subscribed) referenced in the article?